# Sound - how many bytes have been played?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, arrays

I'm playing a `Sound` from a `ByteArray`, and I need to figure out how many bytes have actually been played so far.

- The sound is playing at 44.1KHz
- Milliseconds played so far can be retrieved from `SoundChannel.position`

Knowing the above, I thought the equation would be something like this:

```
((SoundChannel.position / 1000) * 44100) * 2
```

But it seams not, the above never works correctly.

Comment: +1 nice research and attempt.

Comment: in what way doesn't it work correctly?

Comment: @Glitcher I'm using this to try and pause and resume the playback, but on resuming the sound starts at the wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as though you're using the new Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray() or the PCM version. I'd offer that you can't accurately get the position of the ByteArray using that.

Look for an example using the Sound SampleDataEvent listener, where you extract a bunch of samples from the ByteArray (1024,2048,etc) and update a position variable accordingly. You won't do better than storing the position of the ByteArray imho, for most cases it's perfectly fine.

Comment: This is what I had to do in the end, but it only works if you collect 2048 samples. I originally tried with 8192 samples but it's not as fast for pause/resume.

Comment: Ideally I would have liked to calculate, just by knowing the number of seconds played.